# RecyclerView как правильно организовать

Tags: android, recyclerview

Использую в приложений для вывода json во фрагмент `RecyclerView`, в данный момент мой `RecyclerView` загружает весь json, как мне  организовать поэтапную загрузку?

```
   JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Person person = new Person();
                            Log.d("json",obj.getString("image"));
                            person.setId(obj.getString("id"));
                            person.setUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                            person.setName(obj.getString("name") + obj.getString("1"));
                            person.setNumberClient(obj.getString("number"));

                            person.setName2(obj.getString("name"));
                            person.setSurname(obj.getString("surname"));
                            person.setRegion(obj.getString("region"));
                            person.setSubject(obj.getString("1"));
                            names.add(person);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    hidePDialog();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            hidePDialog();

        }
    });
```

вот мой адаптер

```
public class MyPicassoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyHolder> {

    Context c;
    ArrayList<Person> persons;

    public MyPicassoAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Person> persons) {
        this.c = c;
        this.persons = persons;
    }

    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_items,parent,false);
        MyHolder holder=new MyHolder(v);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.nameTxt.setText(persons.get(position).getName());
        holder.id.setText(persons.get(position).getId());
        holder.img_url.setText(persons.get(position).getUrl());
        holder.region.setText(persons.get(position).getRegion());
        holder.subject.setText(persons.get(position).getSubject());
        holder.numClient.setText(persons.get(position).getNumberClient());
        holder.ns.setText(persons.get(position).getName2() + " " + persons.get(position).getSurname());


        PicassoClient.downloadImage(c, "http://www.developer92.16mb.com/mentor/public_html/images/"+persons.get(position).getUrl(), holder.img);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return persons.size();
    }





    public interface ClickListener {
        void onClick(View view, int position);

        void onLongClick(View view, int position);
    }
```

Comment: RecyclerView не может загружать сразу все переданные ему данные, кроме тех случаев, когда они сразу вмещаются на экран устройства. загрузите код, иначе с вашей проблемой трудно будет разобраться.

Comment: Загрузить-то данные он может все сразу. Размерами экрана ограничивается кол-во вьюхолдеров, которые в нем будут отображены. Автор хочет, чтобы данные тоже агружались порциями

Comment: посмотрите пожалуйта добавил код

Comment: да я хочу чтобы json загружался порциями,а не целиком

Comment: И вот еще совет. Если вы выполняете в одной и той же области видимости повторяющийся несколько раз код (например ваш многократный вызов `persons.get(position)`  в методе `onBindViewHolder`), то лучше вынести этот код в отдельную переменную. Код станет чище, будет меньше потенциальных ошибок. Чтобы быстро сделать это, скопируйте повторяющуюся конструкцию и вставьте ее перед первым ее вызовом. Переместите каретку на эту конструкцию, нажмите alt + Enter. В выпадающем списке выберите "introduce local variable", затем "replace all N occurrences". Быстро, удобно, красиво

Comment: Спасибо большое,действительно очень удобно!

Comment: Спасибо большое!действительно очень удобно!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Способ №1:

Повесьте на RecyclerView слушатель прокрутки и, когда он будет прокручен до последнего элемента, подгружайте новую порцию данных.

#### Способ №2:

`@Override
  public void onViewAttachedToWindow(final ViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);
    int layoutPosition = holder.getLayoutPosition();
  }`

В адаптере можно получить позицию только что появившегося элемента списка. Если позиция появившегося элемента последняя, значит пора подгружать новую порцию данных

Comment: Можете на код посмотреть пж

Comment: Спасибо всем разобрался,щас попозже скину может кому нибудь нужно будет